# Ant modified is not working

Tags: ant

I have written code to generate a cache.properties file using `<modified>`

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Analysis" basedir="." default="use">
  <target name="master1">
    <echo message="executing master"/>
    <fileset id="src.files1" dir="D:\CMS\webclient\components\CMS">
      <include name="**/*.uim"/>
      <include name="**/*.properties"/>
      <include name="**/*.vim"/>
      <modified update="true"/>
      <!--    <param name="update" value="true" />-->
      <!--</modified>-->
    </fileset>
    <echo message="task completed"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

The code was working fine but my requirement got changed, then I switched the property to update cache.properties to false and after then its not updating or generating the new cache.properties

I have checked an earlier post also which states that it's a bug that was fixed in ant 1.8 however its not working in ant 1.8

Requires Help

Comment: I came to know that its a bug in ant 1.6 and it got fixed in ant 1.8.https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=32597. So is there any work around or i have to use ant 1.8

Comment: The page you mentioned has listed a work around. Did you try?  In any case, why not upgrade to newer ant - 1.9 is the current version.

Comment: The project requirement is ant 1.6 only and workaround only works for when setting the update to false